# Не запускается сервер daphne

Tags: python, django, websocket, channels

я не могу разобраться с daphne. Развертываю проект на django channels и настроил так, чтобы сервер daphne запускался автоматически, но ни автоматически, ни в ручную он не запускается (точнее запускается и через несколько секунд отключается). Может кто-то сможет помочь? Говорите какой код скинуть.

В консоли: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

Если нужно, то вот daphne.service

```
[Unit]
Description=WebSocket Daphne Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/chat/src
ExecStart=/home/django/chat/venv/bin/python /home/django/chat/venv/bin/daphne -e ssl:8001:privateKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/ilya-shevelev.ru/privkey.pem:certKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/ilya-shevelev.ru/fullchain.pem django_project.asgi:application
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Там используется letsencrypt, возможно проблема в нем, но с ним проблем не наблюдалось.

Comment: что-то в гугл нашли?

Comment: @DaLadno, нашел это вопрос но лучше не стало. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082128/improperlyconfigured-you-must-either-define-the-environment-variable-django-set . Как я понял это если не настроен параметр DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, у меня он настроен, проблема в чем-то другом.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_app.settings")
django.setup()
```

Добавить вверху файла asgi.py

А потом весь остальной код